# Maximum recursion depth while using py2exe

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe, python-2.x

I need to convert my python script into an executable file. I am using `py2exe` but when I try to run the setup.py, I get an error.

> "maximum recursion depth exceeded for python object"?

I am importing many libraries in the code(14 to be specific).

Comment: Please be much more specific. An answer on the questions level of abstraction would be "Try changing what you do." Also, a full trace of the error would be good.

Comment: Any luck with resolving this problem?  I have a minimal python script that just imports pandas and fails with this same error if I try to run py2exe.  I suspect the problem may be because of the Python distribution -- Canopy --  putting pandas somewhere that py2exe has trouble finding.